# Where can I put this counter variable to have it increment correctly?

Tags: javascript, youtube, closures

I'm trying to add a counter  variable so that it only repeats the video 3 times.  However, I can't seem to find a place to put it where 1) the function that uses is can find it.  2) the variable doesn't get reset every time the function is called.  I have created a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/JHicks/pen/QjRxpw) to show you what I mean.  Thanks in advance.

```
//GOALS

//Loop through video.  Increment counter
```

Comment: so you want to show the same clip 3 times in a loop?

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a link to codepen.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have your counter incremented outside, update it to this:

```
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
             counter++;
             player.seekTo(50);
          }
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I needed.